# Is $0$ an accumulation point of $a_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider $a_n=\frac{x^n}{1+x^{2n}} , x \in \mathbb{R} $

For $|x|<1$ holds  $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n =0$

Therefore 0 is an accumulation point.

Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Why "for $|x|<1$" ??

Comment: @Arthur: did I say that ?

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we actually have $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n = 0$ whenever $|x|\neq 1$. For $|x|<1$, the numerator goes to $0$ and the denominator goes to $1$, and for $|x|>1$, the denominator grows much faster than the numerator, so $a_n$ still goes to $0$.

For $x = 1$, we have $a_n = \frac12$, which also converges, and for $x = -1$, we get $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}2$, which doesn't converge.

With the convergence analysis out of the way, let's see what we can say about accumulation points.

If each $a_n$ is considered to be a function of $x$, then you would want the accumulation points to be functions as well. In this case, there are two accumulation points, $f_+$ and $f_-$, given by:
$$
f_\pm(x) = \cases{\frac12 & if $x = 1$\\\pm\frac12 & if $x = -1$\\0 & otherwise}
$$
If we instead consider $(a_n)_{n = 1}^\infty$ to be an infinite collection of sequences (one sequence for each real number $x$), then *most* of these sequences have only $0$ as their only accumulation point, as they converge to $0$. However, if $|x| = 1$, then $0$ is not an accumulation point. For $x = 1$ we get $\frac12$ as accumulation point instead, and for $x = -1$ we have the two accumulation points $\pm\frac12$.

Comment: Thank  you very much:)